# How should I care for a sunburned coffee plant?

Tags: houseplants, indoors, plant-health, plant-care, sunlight

We have a coffee plant which lives indoors. Our house is reasonably dark so every now and then we take it outside when the sun isn't very bright. A week or so ago, the sun suddenly came out while we weren't home and the plant got quite badly burned. The leaves are now dropping and I'm quite concerned about whether it'll recover.

Is there anything I can do to promote new leaf growth? Or will the plant recover on its own, given time?

[image: The tree]
[image: Closeup of a leaf]

Comment: You haven't seen any spider mites on the leaf undersides, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, if there are no pests involved (there often are), what you want to do is provide as 'comfortable' of conditions as possible while the plant recovers. Water normally, don't over- or under-water. Keep it in bright, filtered light out of direct sun, and keep the humidity as high as possible. Fertilize lightly with a balanced all-purpose fertilizer.

The plant should recover nicely given time. Don't stimulate super fast growth, or it will be leggy and have bad form. Potted coffee plants seem to drop leaves for the smallest reasons, ime, but usually recover well. Your plant looks rather OK.